# parse json file to get specific fields for each date in it

Tags: python, json

I have a bunch of json files that look like this:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-03-12",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-03-12": {
        "1. open": "120.4000",
        "2. high": "121.1700",
        "3. low": "119.1600",
        "4. close": "121.0300",
        "5. volume": "88105050"
    },
    "2021-03-11": {
        "1. open": "122.5400",
        "2. high": "123.2100",
        "3. low": "121.2600",
        "4. close": "121.9600",
        "5. volume": "103026514"
    },
    "2021-03-10": {
        "1. open": "121.6900",
        "2. high": "122.1700",
        "3. low": "119.4500",
        "4. close": "119.9800",
            "5. volume": "111943326"
        }
    }
}
```

and they go on all the way back to "2020-10-19". My ultimate goal is to calculate the average of each field (open, high, low, close, volume) and plot it, showing how many times each field went below its average, I think I got how to get the required values for each file, by using Fstrings:

```
opening = data['Time Series (Daily)'][f'{date}'][f'{field}']
```

My question is: is there an easy way to parse the json file, to get the {date} and {field} values for each date in Time-Series?

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in that JSON. Look at the top-level Object: `{ "Meta-Data" : { }, { } }`. It looks like you have an unnamed object within the top-level Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.keys()` function of a dictionary to get a list of keys. Here's an example to calculate the opening average:

```
dates = data['Time Series (Daily)'].keys()
openingSum = 0

for date in dates:
    opening = data['Time Series (Daily)'][date][f'{field}']
    openingSum += float(opening)

openingAverage = openingSum / len(prices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting your json to d and reading directly to a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d["Time Series (Daily)"]).T
```

Output

```
           1. open 2. high  3. low 4. close  5. volume
2021-03-12  120.40  121.17  119.16   121.03   88105050
2021-03-11  122.54  123.21  121.26   121.96  103026514
2021-03-10  121.69  122.17  119.45   119.98  111943326
```